# 'android.content.Intent com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-intent, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google sign-in into my app but i keep getting this error `'android.content.Intent com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent()' on a null object reference`.

I followed the tutorial from the firebase website here --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Here's my code

```
private void googleSignIn() {

    Intent intent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(Objects.requireNonNull(account));
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w("hhm", "Google signin failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you **initialized** the `googleSignInClient` Object?

It seems like your `googleSignInClient` is **null**, and needs to be initialized:

> 1-In your sign-in activity's onCreate method, configure Google Sign-In
>   to request the user data required by your app...
>
> 2-Then, also in your sign-in activity's onCreate method, create a
>   GoogleSignInClient object with the options you specified.

```
// Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
// profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

// Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked..it was a silly mistake I made. Thanks for pointing it out I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, i I also had problems like you and this is how I resolved

```
 private Boolean checkgglogin(){
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account != null){
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
    }
//then add checkgglogin to if requestCode
// Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && checkgglogin()) {
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
```